# How to edit records using reports in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access

I created a report using query which shows all the records from one table, each rows of report shows one by one records of the table. Now i want to delete the records in same report, i created one button and each row generates same buttons and perform same deletion it works. Now i also want to edit(update) my records. So i added one more button edit, now when i click the records in any rows of that report cursor entered to particular textbox but cannot modify the value inside it. I want to update records using same report and edit command button, i think it may be set to read only but i cud not find it in propery window of text box, This Report is automatically generated by clicking the query and it loads result of that query is that reason for my problem?

Comment: Forms are for editing, reports are for output.

Comment: Do you mean click the records in the "Query" instead of the Report? If so, perhaps your query is not updateable. Perhaps you could post the SQL and if it is selecting from more than one table, the relationships between the tables.

Comment: It sounds like you are modifying your data through a query.  I would recommend using the Form wizard to develop a basic user input and modification form. You can set your form to pull up as much or as little data from a combo box filter, then delete the unwanted informtaion.  Or you could in your SQL in design mode at the bottom of your field you wish to filter by add teh statment "Like "something*" and that will bring up only the fields with the "something" in the value field, or a Not Like"something*" to exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a form using the Form Wizard.  That should allow you to make new records, edit existing records, and even delete records fairly easily.

Reports are read only and intending for printing to paper.  Putting buttons in a report to delete records is not what reports in Access was designed for.